# Displaying boolean values as images

Tags: visualforce

I want to display boolean values as images.

I have a checkbox in a table, if it is checked it should display a tick mark image and if it isn't checked it should display a cross image.

Answer (score 11):

Simplistically, you can do something like:

```
<apex:image URL="{!if(checked,"/img/checked.gif","/img/unchecked.gif")}/>
```

Where each icon represents a checked or unchecked box. The exact URL will differ, but the concept remains. There is a default checked and unchecked box, or you could use one of your own choosing by using static resources.

Answer (score 7):

If you've got images to use then the other two answers will fit the bill nicely... an alternative though (to avoid a regular checkbox) could be to use unicode characters for the job, and you could adjust the font size and colour accordingly.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(checked, '✔', '✘')}"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you'd like to do this in a standard page layout (ie. without using the otherwise perfect visualforce example by sfdcfox) you can use a Formula field to output images based on other field values as you can see in the [documentation on advanced formula fields here](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=useful_advanced_formulas_image_links.htm&language=en_US).

As an example for your request, a formula field something like

```
IF( checked__c, 
IMAGE("/img/checked.gif", "Checked"),
IMAGE("/img/unchecked.gif", "Not Checked")
)
```

Would put an image field on the standard view page for your object.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to output the HTML code directly:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(checked__c)}">&#9744;</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText rendered="{!checked__c}">&#9745;</apex:outputText>
```